# How to alert the user on a chatbot?

Tags: bots, webhooks, skype, chatbot, dialogflow-es

How to alert the user on a particular day at a particular time ? Has anyone come across any specific issue such as this ? I am using API.AI/ Dialogflow here .  Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a Dialogflow API for push notifications/proactive messaging, although you can implement this yourself in conjunction with Dialogflow.

Comment: Thank you for the answer . I understand that . I am trying to implement using Dialogflow itself . Any idea on how to do so ?

Comment: @jane this all depends on the integration platform, but it's something you'd have to write yourself. However, there are some libraries (like Skype4J and JavaSkype) that let you connect to the Skype Desktop API and send messages directly to users. Your webhook could for example use such library to mass message users.

Comment: It depends on the integration you'd like to work with, but the short answer is: use the authentication information you've supplied to Dialogflow to identify your bot on your target platform and use that auth info to send messages to users.  You'll have to keep track of users that both use your Dialogflow using some sort of ID supplied by the target platform.